# Does using dynamic prototypes in UITableView prevent the use of the Storyboard for laying out cell UI?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm a bit confused here. I have a view controller with a UITableView in it and I'm using a custom UITableViewCell class.

My understanding is that using dynamic prototypes and a custom class gives me programatic control over the cells. That has its uses, but I can also see the advantage of using the Storyboard for laying out UI as well.

However, I've noticed that nothing I create in the Storyboard within the cell shows up. I can create and connect IBOutlets/IBActions from the Storyboard to the UITableViewCell.swift class, but they don't actually seem to work/display. The table view just ends up showing what's in the custom UITableViewCell.swift class and ignores anything added to the cell view Storyboard.

So my question is: Can I use both, or do I have to stick with one or the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very common to design your cell in Storyboard as a Prototype and then also include code in your cell class to configure / customize it dynamically. So, that's not an issue.

Most likely, you missed something that is not entirely clear when getting started...

If your cell class is **NOT** connected to a Storyboard Prototype cell, you *must* register it:

```
tableView.register(MyCustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
```

However, if your cell class **IS** connected to a Storyboard Prototype cell, you *cannot* do that... it will be registered as reusable when it is instantiated from the Storyboard.

So, if you have that line (probably in your `viewDidLoad()`) remove it and you should see your cell with the Storyboard UI elements.

Comment: Is there a benefit of using one or the other? I currently have it configured as your first example, where it's NOT connected to the storyboard and is registered.

I guess it's not clear to me what the benefits/difference is.

Comment: There are pros and cons to each approach. I think most folks simply develop a preference over time. Personally, my work projects do not use IB at all. However, when designing a new controller / cell / custom view / etc, I'll often lay it out in IB to see the visual and quickly run it to confirm it's correct, and then write the code to replicate it.